# SELECT query with optional values

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I am looking for a simple query to return one single line from one table.

I have a table which has a key column and some more column which can be NULL. The table is not sorted in any way.

Here is an example table:

```
| KEY | ValCol1 | ValCol2 | ValCol3 |

|  1  |     123 |     222 |  NULL   |

|  2  |   NULL  |     333 |  NULL   |

|  3  |   NULL  |  NULL   |     abc |

|  4  |   NULL  |  NULL   |  NULL   |   <- Default-Column

|  5  |    999  |  NULL   |     bbb |

|  6  |    123  |   444   |     bbb |
```

For all the nullable columns I have now a value to search in the table:

Search Values: ValCol1 = `123`,  ValCol2 = `444`,  ValCol3 = `abc`

These search values should now give me the key 3 because at least the third column gives me a match.

If no match at all could be found the query should return the last row with all NULL values. If there would be a match with tho column the query should return this Key:

E.g.

Search Values: ValCol1 = `123`,  ValCol2 = `444`,  ValCol3 = `abc`

Returns Key 6 -> it's the most precise key

Comment: The first requirement can be addressed with a simple `OR` in the `WHERE` statement.

Comment: I don't think it's that simple. When I work with 'OR IS NULL' I will get more than one column back and not only the most precise.

Comment: You don't need the `OR IS NULL` part, just `OR` the values as shown in the answer. Don't add the values in the `ORDER BY` though, this won't work

Comment: why should it not return not KEY 1 ? Seems just as good a match as KEY 3. What did you try ? That may give us a hint of what is on your mind

Comment: @t-clausen.dk It should not return KEY 1 because ValCol2 in my search is 444 and in the table it is 222. However if KEY 1 in my table would be 444 at ValCol2 it then should return KEY 1 because it would than be more specific than KEY 3

Comment: `It should not return KEY 1 because ValCol2 in my search is 444`. Your `ValCol1 = 123,` is at row with KEY 1. Row 1 should be in result output if we follow your logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will rank the rows after most hits:

```
--Test data:

DECLARE @t table([KEY] int identity(1,1), ValCol1 char(3), 
                  ValCol2 char(3), ValCol3 char(3))

INSERT @t values
('123','222',NULL),
(NULL,'333',NULL),
(NULL,NULL,'abc'),
(NULL,NULL,NULL)-- <- Default-Column


DECLARE @ValCol1 char(3)= 123
DECLARE @ValCol2 char(3)= 444
DECLARE @ValCol3 char(3)= 'abc'

--Query:

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  [KEY], ValCol1, ValCol2, ValCol3, 
      CASE WHEN ValCol1 = @ValCol1 
           THEN 100
           WHEN ValCol1 <> @ValCol1 
           THEN 0
           ELSE 10 END +
      CASE WHEN ValCol2 = @ValCol2
           THEN 100
           WHEN ValCol2 <> @ValCol2
           THEN 0
           ELSE 10 END +
      CASE WHEN ValCol3 = @ValCol3
           THEN 100
           WHEN ValCol3 <> @ValCol3
           THEN 0
           ELSE 10 END BestMatchrating
    FROM @t 
    WHERE 
      ValCol1 = @ValCol1 or 
      ValCol2 = @ValCol2 or 
      ValCol3 = @ValCol3 or
      (ValCol1 is null and ValCol2 is null and ValCol3 is null)
)
SELECT TOP 1 [KEY], ValCol1, ValCol2, ValCol3
FROM 
  CTE
ORDER BY   
  BestMatchrating DESC
```

Result:

```
KEY  ValCol1  ValCol2  ValCol3
3    NULL     NULL     abc
```

Comment: this will consider NULL higher ranking than a wrong match

Comment: thank you for your solution. It worked without a problem. All I had to change was to change the wrong match value from 0 to -1000 because I don't want a wrong value in any case in my result set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( K INT, V1 INT, V2 INT, V3 INT )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, 123, 222, NULL ),
        ( 2, NULL, 333, NULL ),
        ( 3, NULL, NULL, 444 ),
        ( 4, NULL, NULL, NULL );
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY CASE WHEN v1 IS NULL
                                                              AND v2 IS NULL
                                                              AND v3 IS NULL
                                                          THEN 1
                                                          ELSE 0
                                                     END, K ) AS rn
               FROM     @t
               WHERE    V1 = 123
                        OR V2 = 444
                        OR V3 = 444
                        OR ( V1 IS NULL
                             AND V2 IS NULL
                             AND V3 IS NULL
                           )
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte
    WHERE   rn = 1
```

Output:

```
K   V1  V2  V3
1   123 222 NULL
```

Comment: null has a higher match value than a wrong value to value match, sp row 3 would be a better match in this case. That is more obvious in the updated question

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution looks like this:

```
declare @valCol3 nvarchar(50) = 'abc'
declare @valCol2 nvarchar(50) = '444'
declare @valCol1 nvarchar(50) = '123'

select top 1 * from (
    select *, 0 as priority
      from #tmp
     where [ValCol1] is null 
       and [ValCol2] is null 
       and [ValCol3] is null

     union

    select *, 1 as priority
      from #tmp
     where [ValCol3] = @valCol3

    union

    select *, 2 as priority
      from #tmp
     where [ValCol2] = @valCol2 
       and [ValCol3] = @valCol3

     union

    select *, 3 as priority
      from #tmp
     where [ValCol1] = @valCol1 
       and [ValCol2] = @valCol2 
       and [ValCol3] = @valCol3
    ) as t1
order by t1.priority desc
```

Init table query:

```
create table #tmp (
    [Key] bigint, 
    [ValCol1] nvarchar(50), 
    [ValCol2] nvarchar(50),
    [ValCol3] nvarchar(50)
)
insert into #tmp values (1, '123', '222', null)
insert into #tmp values (2, null, '333', null)
insert into #tmp values (3, null, null, 'abc')
insert into #tmp values (4, null, null, null)
```

Comment: what happens if there is a match on column 1 and column 3 ? Or column 1 and 2 ? or only on column 1 only (or 2). Seems you have left out many posibilities. If this check should be extended to 5 columns, I would love to read your code, but hate to maintain it.

Comment: no, as I wrote it doesn't solve the problem at all. and it is not more simple than my answer. Using union will also slow down query

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT KEY FROM table 
WHERE (ValCol1 = '123' or ValCol1 is null) 
And (ValCol2 = '444' or ValCol2 is null) 
And (ValCol3 = 'abc' or ValCol3 is null)
```

This will return KEY `3` and `4`. If `ValCol3` is not `'abc'`. It should return you `4`.

Comment: You are not addressing the issue of finding the best match.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT top 1 max(Key)
FROM
(
  SELECT "match" as "resultSet", * FROM table 
  WHERE
  (ValCol1 = "123" OR ValCol2 = "444" OR ValCol3 = "abc")
  union 
  SELECT "default" as "resultSet",  * FROM table 
  WHERE
  (ValCol1 IS NULL AND ValCol2 IS NULL AND ValCol3 IS NULL)
) a
Group by resultSet
order by max(Key)
```

Comment: ORDER BY ValCol1+ValCol2+ValCol3 ... order by null ? If any of the values are null, then the whole expression is null. Also different issues in your code

Comment: This does not solve my problem in general. However you are right, that this query does solve my simplified example. But it does not always work if I have two matching values. In this case it does not necessary return the most precise match.

Comment: @Wawrzyniec sorry your solution is still not correct. I have tested it. It creates a match as soon as one ValColX-column has the correct value. But if the other ValColX-columns do not match it still creates the match. Besides that my table is not sorted in any way. In my simplified example the default row is the last one - this is a coincidence

Comment: Ok. I addmit I don't undesrtand the problem at all. Gl with finding the solution!